# Load third-party JS from the server only when needed in single-page app

Tags: javascript, ajax, requirejs, browserify

What I am looking to do is load some JS dependencies, but only when my application is going to need them, and to do this on the fly.  The main goal is performance.

I am working on a single-page application built primarily using AJAX.  All of the javascript for the application is separated into distinct chunks, which I combine and minify using Gulp.  The directory structure is similar to below, before the build.

```html
src
  js
    _one.js
    _two.js
    _three.js
```

I'm using Bower to import a number of weighty third-party dependencies for the app, which right now get concatenated into my main scripts file along with my code. **The primary issue is that some of the dependencies are large files, but don't necessarily get utilized by every user.**

What I essentially want, in the single page app, is to be able to wrap a function in a require statement that will prompt the browser to download the needed dependency immediately, and then for the function to load.  This needs to happen without a page refresh.

I looked into RequireJS and Browserify, but it seemed like with those you are just separating the dependencies into separate bundles, which you load anyway.  As I said, the goal here is faster load times and better performance overall.

Comment: simplest way: make more than one browserify build, and load the one you need from the page...

Comment: I don't really know how one could accomplish this outside of writing some sort of dependency injection system which lazy loads the dependencies. I understand that the dependencies can have large file sizes, but how much does this really affect your application if the content is delivered gzipped?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you've tried? Can simply using nested require calls do the trick? https://jsfiddle.net/hynding/1u41smu7/

Comment: @SteveHynding this helped me make sense of things, and now I have it working.  Thanks!

Comment: Very good, I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a DI framework like BottleJS?

https://github.com/young-steveo/bottlejs

Answer (score 0):

I appears using nested require calls to do your lazy loading is what you're essentially looking for:

```
define("/path/1", ["jquery"], function($) {
  $("#path1").text('In 5 seconds, angular will be loaded. The current type is:'+ typeof angular);

  setTimeout(function(){
    require(["angular"], function(angular){
        $("#path2").text('Angular has been loaded. The current type is:'+typeof angular);
    });
  }, 5000);
});

require(["/path/1"]);
```

In this example, Angular has not been loaded when "/path/1" is called upon on the last line. Only after five seconds does the nested require get called and angular is loaded.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/hynding/1u41smu7/